# php form will not submit unless the checkbox is ticked

Tags: php, mysql

my form is unable to submit unless the checkbox is ticked, I am really unsure as to why this is.

further, if the checkbox is ticked it fails to update the database, there is no issue with the function I am using or the query as i have checked that directly on the db.

Any help would be hugely appreciated, and please feel free to ask any questions if there is anymore information i can give

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';
protect_page();
include 'includes/overall/header.php';
$page = $_GET['page'];
$email = $_GET['user'];
$p_id = project_id_from_project_name($page);
$supervisor = supervisor_from_email($email, $p_id);
$user_id = user_id_from_email($email);
?>
<h1>Add A User to the Project</h1>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['form_submit']) === true && empty($_GET['form_submit']) === false) {
    echo 'You\'re user has been added successfully!<br /><br />';
    echo '<a href="projects.php">Please click here to return to Your Projects</a>';
} else {
    if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
        $page = $_GET['page'];  
        $p_id = project_id_from_project_name($page);
        $supervisor_update = ($_POST['supervisor'] == 1) ? 1 : 0;


        $update_project_member_data = array(
            'project_id'            => "$p_id",
            'project_name'          => "$page",
            'project_member_id'     => "$user_id",
            'supervisor'            => "$supervisor_update"
        );

        update_project_member_data($p_id, $update_project_member_data);

        header('Location: update_user.php?page=' . $page .'&user=' . $email .'&form_submit=1');
        exit();

    } else if (empty($errors) === false) {
        echo output_errors($errors);
    }
?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <ul>
            <li>
                Email Address: &nbsp; <?php echo $email ?>
            </li>
            <li>
                Set user as Supervisor?<br />
                <input name="supervisor" type="checkbox" <?php if ($supervisor == 1) {?> checked="checked"<?php }?>/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="submit" value="Update User">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>

<?php 
}
include 'includes/overall/footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: show your javascript code.

Comment: you have not value attr in checkbox

Comment: There is no javascript code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is with the condition you have:

```
empty($_POST) === false
```

Since your form is very basic and only has the one input.  The $_POST array is only populated with values when that input is checked.  Unchecked it doesn't pass any values in the $_POST array.  Normally, the submit button would pass a value, but since you didn't have the "name" attribute on there, it doesn't.

You can either try adding the name attribute to the submit button or just add a hidden value inside the FORM element such as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submitted" />
```

Comment: Hi Thank you! My form is now submitting, however it is not updating the database, please any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening here is that there is no data to post if you do not check the box. You can check for the request method, $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']  instead of empty($_POST).

edit: to clarify, the post happens but the if condition evaluates to false